# powers of Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $0<\alpha\leq 1$. I call a  Lebesgue measurable set $E\subseteq \mathbb R^n$  an 
 $\alpha$-null set if for every $\epsilon>0$ there are countably many balls $B_j$ such that
$$\mbox{$\displaystyle E\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_j$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\sigma_n(B_j)\right)^\alpha<\epsilon$}.$$

It is easy to see that any $\alpha$-null set has Lebesgue measure zero. The converse is not true.
Is there a simple explicit example showing this?

Comment: What is $\sigma_{n}$ here? Lebesgue measure?

Comment: yes, $\sigma_n$ is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: maybe the Cantor set?